# how to overload << operator for YAML::Emitter to serialize a custom class containing vector of another custom class

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, yaml-cpp

In my application, I have a class that contains a vector of another class and I am unable to write overloaded YAML::Emitter& operator<< for this.

To illustrate, I have written the bellow file which reproduces the error:

class Department contains a vector of Employee and I need to output the Department with all employees in Yaml format.

I get the following weird error that does not seem to match my method signatures:

> $ g++ ta.cpp -L ~/yaml-cpp/lib/ -I ../Thanga/yaml/yaml-cpp-0.5.1/include/  -lyamlcpp 2>&1|more
>   ...
>   ta.cpp:37:16: note: YAML::Emitter& operator<<(YAML::Emitter&, Department&)
>   ta.cpp:37:16: note:   **no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const Employee’ to ‘Department&’**
>   ta.cpp:28:16: note: YAML::Emitter& operator<<(YAML::Emitter&, Employee&)
>   ta.cpp:28:16: note:   **no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const Employee’ to ‘Employee&’**

Here is the complete source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Employee
{
        std::string name;
        std::string surname;
        int age;
        std::string getName(){return name;}
        std::string getSurname(){return surname;}
        int getAge(){return age;}
};

struct Department
{
    std::string name;
    int headCount;
    std::vector<Employee>  staff;
    std::string getName(){return name;}
    int getHeadCount(){return headCount;}
    std::vector<Employee> & getStaff(){return staff;}
};

YAML::Emitter& operator << (YAML::Emitter& out, Employee& e) {
        out << YAML::BeginMap;
        out << YAML::Key <<"name"<<YAML::Value <<e.getName();
        out << YAML::Key <<"surname"<<YAML::Value <<e.getSurname();
        out << YAML::Key <<"age"<<YAML::Value <<e.getAge();
        out << YAML::EndMap;
        return out;
}

YAML::Emitter& operator << (YAML::Emitter& out, Department& d) {
        out << YAML::BeginMap;
        out << YAML::Key <<"name"<<YAML::Value <<d.getName();
        out << YAML::Key <<"headCount"<<YAML::Value <<d.getHeadCount();
        out << YAML::Key <<"Employees"<<YAML::Value <<d.getStaff();
        out << YAML::EndMap;
        return out;
}


int main()
{
    Employee k;
    Department d;

    d.name="Twidlers";
    d.headCount=5;

    k.name="harry";
    k.surname="person";
    k.age=70;
    d.staff.push_back(k);

    k.name="joe";
    k.surname="person";
    k.age=30;
    d.staff.push_back(k);

    k.name="john";
    k.surname="doe";
    k.age=50;
    d.staff.push_back(k);

    std::ofstream ofstr("output.yaml");
    YAML::Emitter out;
    out<<d;
    ofstr<<out.c_str();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overloads provided for `vector` take a `const std::vector<T>&`, so you'll have to sprinkle some extra `const`s throughout:

```
YAML::Emitter& operator << (YAML::Emitter& out, const Employee& e)
...
YAML::Emitter& operator << (YAML::Emitter& out, const Department& d)
```

and then put them on your member functions, e.g.:

```
const std::vector<Employee>& getStaff() const { return staff; }
```

(In general, you should make your getters const by default, and if you need to mutate state, add setters instead of non-const getters.)

Comment: Thanks Jesse! Like other posters said, the care and support you give to yaml-cpp is unprecedented, keep up the good work!